# What does the logic look like to capture input on Entry with GTK/Rust?

Tags: rust

I am a React developer that is learning GTK version 3 with Rust. I am now working with Entry which is the equivalent to HTML input elements.

In React we have a value prop on an input element and you can extract in the browser via `event.target.value`.

How does that work when working with GTK/Rust Entry?

Again, in React I can do something like this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <input value={term} onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And console log the input provided. Now in the world of GTK I have done something like this:

```
fn build(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
  .entry("input_element")
    .with_entry(|input_element| {
      input_element.set_max_length(MAX_DESCRIPTION_LEN);
    })
  .end("input_element")
}
```

Is there a way to console log or read a value typed into the `entry` to verify it's receiving user input?

I know there is also event handling in GTK Rust with something like a button like so:

```
fn handle_change(&mut self, button: &Button) {
  let name = button.widget_name();
  if name.eq("button_name_text") {
    *self.button_name_text.borrow_mut() = button.clone();
  }
}
```

If there is also event handling to capture the input entered, what would that logic look like?

Comment: I think you want [`EditableSignals::connect_changed`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/trait.EditableSignals.html#tymethod.connect_changed) along with a `println!("")` - something like `something.connect_changed(|value| println!("{value:?}")` but I can't test it myself right now. `Entry` implements the `EditableSignals` trait, so it should have the `connect_changed` method.

Comment: @Tigregalis, thank you, could you add that as an answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EditableSignals::connect_changed`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/trait.EditableSignals.html#tymethod.connect_changed).

[`Entry`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/struct.Entry.html) [implements the `EditableSignals` trait](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/struct.Entry.html#implements), so it has the `connect_changed` method.

To get the text, you use the [`text`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/git/docs/gtk/prelude/trait.EntryExt.html#tymethod.text) method which `Entry` has via the extension trait `EntryExt`.

You can print using the [`println!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.println.html) macro.

For example:

```rust
input_element.connect_changed(|target| {
    println!("You entered: {:?}", target.text());
    // `input_element` and `target` refer to the same `Entry`
});
```

---

Working standalone example:
[image: Result]

```rust
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let application =
        gtk::Application::new(Some("stackoverflow.questions_75710906"), Default::default());

    application.connect_activate(|application| {
        let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(application);

        let input_element = gtk::Entry::new();

        // ...
        input_element.connect_changed(|target| {
            println!("You entered: {:?}", target.text());
            // `input_element` and `target` refer to the same `Entry`
        });
        // ...

        window.add(&input_element);

        window.show_all();
    });

    application.run();
}
```